# Data binding to a ViewModel property from a collections Binding?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I will try to keep this as succinct as possible.

- I have a ViewModel with a collection of Models (i.e. Airplanes).
- I have a Xaml page that is binded to the ViewModel.
- The Xaml page has a DataGrid that is binded to the Airplanes collections.
- For one of the DataGrid column templates, I want it to show a list of "EngineComponents", **where EngineComponents is a collection of items defined in the ViewModel.**

The catch is this:
The EngineComponents is a collection of parts that is essentially static. All Airplance rows in the DataGrid should show the same list of EngineComponents.

> Airplanes

How to solve this EngineComponents binding question without writing extra code (event handlers, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a RelativeSource. I'll use a ListView in my example, but the ideas the same.

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding ...}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Airplanes}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Drawing No." Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailableAirplanes,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Airplane}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```